# App Repo vs Package Repo?

Tags: centos, fedora, repository

1. What is the difference between an "app repository" like EPEL / RPMForge / etc and a "package repo" like [PkgDB](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/)?
2. Can I point yum / df to pkgDB so it can figure out where to download stuff from without having to create a bunch of .repo files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PkgDB is official Fedora package repository **for Fedora**, which is accessible using your `fedora.repo` and `fedora-updates.repo` files on Fedora. You don't need to add anything to default Fedora installation to have it working (if you are using up-to date Fedora version). If you want to use it on different distro (RHEL, CentOS), you can download the packages from [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/), but it will probably not work.

On the other hand, EPEL contains some Fedora rebuild for  for RHEL and CentOS, based on Fedora packages, but not all of them are there and they are not update in the same pace as Fedora versions. The RPMForge contains also RHEL/CentOS, but it is third-party source. These are not useful for Fedora systems.

You can install EPEL repo using this command (on RHEL7):

```
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-6.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-6.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: got it! thanks, so in the end they are both app repos just a different name.

Comment: @Fawix Yes, that's basically right, although we don't necessarily use the term "app repo", since not every package is an _application_. (Some are tools or libraries or even data.)